# How to remove digital signature from an MSI installer?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-installer, code-signing

I can't seem to find a way to remove a digital signature from an `.msi` file that was previously added to it by the [signtool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387764%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: A .msi is persisted as a COM Structured Storage. In some quick searches I've not found any specific information on how digital signatures are applied to this format, so the answer may be specific to Windows Installer.

Comment: @MichaelUrman: It's strange that `signtool` provides an option to sign an `.msi` file but not to remove the signature. Unless I'm missing some parameter?

Answer (score 2):

Was in a similar situation: I customized a vendor-supplied MSI file, which invalidated the original digital signature. I then needed to remove (delete entirely, rather than replace) that signature, so that my users would not get errors when downloading and running the file on Windows 10.

Tried InstallShield, XML2MSI, msidb and an array of different MSI editors to no avail. What ultimately worked for me was to remove the digital signature stream (in my case it was called "[5]DigitalSignature") from the [MSI Compound File](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/openspecification/2009/07/24/exploring-the-compound-file-binary-format/) using an editor.

Personally, I used [MiTeC's Structured Storage Viewer](http://www.mitec.cz/ssv.html) to do this, but other tools may work for you.

*Note: the SSV displayed garbage for some of the stream names in my MSI, but still worked correctly.*

Answer (score 1):

Performing an [administrative installation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367541(v=vs.85).aspx) removes the digital signature from the package. An administrative installation modifies the installation package in order to add the AdminProperties stream, which would invalidate the original digital signature. An administrator can resign the package.

Comment: OK. Good find. But I don't want to install this MSI. Would it still work to remove digital signature?